# Plotting attributes of vertices in WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[n, p, k]

Tags: plotting, functions, graphs-and-networks, charts, attributes

I have a graph `WS = RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[n, p, k]]`.
I need to plot several characteristics of each `v`: the clustering coefficient, number of triples at `v`, eccentricity, vertex centrality, closeness, and betweenness. 
I'm relatively inexperienced with Mathematica and quite lost on how to achieve this. 
I don't expect the exact lines of the solution, I'd just like some pointers on how to approach this. First of all, how do I get a set of all the vertices of `WS`? Then, how do I get the values of the different measures for each `v` in `WS`?

Comment: [Clustering coefficient](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LocalClusteringCoefficient.html). [Eccentricity](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EccentricityCentrality.html)? [Vertex centrality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexDegree.html)? (Or see _See Also_ section) [Closeness](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClosenessCentrality.html). [Betweenness](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BetweennessCentrality.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Using `` GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart `` for displaying vertex attributes:

```
SeedRandom[777]
ws = RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[6, 0.6, 2]];
centralities = {LocalClusteringCoefficient, EccentricityCentrality, 
   VertexDegree, ClosenessCentrality, BetweennessCentrality,  EigenvectorCentrality};
Through[centralities[ws]] // 
 Style[TableForm[Round[#, .001], TableHeadings -> {centralities, VertexList[ws]}], 
   FontFamily -> "Calibri", 24] &
```

[image]

```
Legended[GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[RemoveProperty[ws, VertexLabels], 
 Automatic -> (#[ws] + .1), 
 ImageSize -> 300, ChartStyle -> 63], 
 Placed[Style[#, 20, "Panel"], {1/2, 97/100} ]] & /@ 
    centralities /. False -> True // 
Partition[#, 3] & // Grid
```

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

Using the built-in functions mentioned in @Oska's comment:

```
ws = RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[6, 0.1, 2]]; 
centralities = {LocalClusteringCoefficient,  EccentricityCentrality, 
    VertexDegree, ClosenessCentrality, BetweennessCentrality}; 
Through[centralities[ws]] // Style[TableForm[Round[#, .001], 
      TableHeadings -> {centralities, VertexList[ws]}], FontFamily -> "Calibri", 24] &
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting choice of font.

Comment: @m_goldberg, Office 2010 default font family:)

Comment: Your answer and @Oska's comment were very helpful. Your efforts are appreciated.

Comment: @bhkj I only Googled what you typed. See [here](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=clustering+coefficient+mathematica#) and [here](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Betweenness+mathematica&l=1).

Comment: @bhkj, glad it was useful for you. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 1):

There's one measure you were asking for missing from the existing answer:

> number of triples at `v`

This can be obtained efficiently using [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM)'s `IGAdjacentTriangleCount` function.

```
?IGAdjacentTriangleCount
```

> `IGAdjacentTriangleCount[graph]` counts the triangles each vertex
>   participates in. Edge directions are ignored.
>
> `IGAdjacentTriangleCount[graph, vertex]` counts the triangles vertex
>   participates in.
>
> `IGAdjacentTriangleCount[graph, {vertex1, vertex2, ...}]` counts the triangles the specified vertices participate
>   in.

---

It can also be implemented in pure Mathematica very concisely (though less efficiently) using the fact that if $A$ is the graph's adjacency matrix, then $(A^k)_{ij}$ contains the number of ways we can get from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$ in $k$ hops.  Thus $(A^3)_{ii}$ gives twice the number of triangles that $i$ participates in (twice because the triangle, i.e. 3-loop, can be traversed in two directions).

---

```
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}];

IGAdjacentTriangleCount[g]
(* {0, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6, 0, 9, 0, 2} *)

With[{am = AdjacencyMatrix[g]},
 Normal@Diagonal[am.am.am]/2
 ]
(* {0, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6, 0, 9, 0, 2} *)
```

---

As for visualizing these, these days I much prefer doing this with IGraph/M (disclosure: I'm the author). Here's a simple example:

```
RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[20, 0.2]] // 
 IGVertexMap[ColorData["SolarColors"], VertexStyle -> Rescale@*BetweennessCentrality]
```

[image]

The measures you are asking for are available as the following builtin an IGraph/M functions:

- clustering coefficient: `LocalClusteringCoefficient`, `IGLocalClusteringCoefficient`
- number of triples: `IGAdjacentTriangleCount`
- eccentricity: `VertexEccentricity` (for one vertex), `EccentricityCentrality` (inverse), `IGEccentricity`
- vertex centrality: I don't know what you mean
- closeness: `ClosenessCentrality`, `IGCloseness`, `IGClosenessEstimate` (for big graphs)
- betweenness: `BetweennessCentrality`, `IGBetweenness`, `IGBetweennessEstimate` (for big graph)

Here's a nicer plot of all of them, also showing off `IGWattsStrogatzGame`, which supports some additional features not available with `WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution`.

```
g = IGWattsStrogatzGame[20, 0.2, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", VertexSize -> Large, GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack"]

Labeled[IGVertexMap[ColorData["Rainbow"], VertexStyle -> Rescale@*#, g], #] & /@
     {LocalClusteringCoefficient, IGAdjacentTriangleCount, IGEccentricity, ClosenessCentrality, BetweennessCentrality}
```

[image]